# Linq: multiple relationships to same table

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the same problem as [this guy](http://forums.oreilly.com/content/C-3-0-in-a-Nutshell/775/Linq-To-Sql-Classes-With-Multiple-Relationships-To-A-Table/):

I have a table that has references my tblstaff table twice for two different people.  Now that I have added this second reference neither of them work.

What is up w/ that?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a function to getStaffbyID and manually call it when I wanted the name instead of the id.

```
    Dim id As String = 1
    Session("BusinessPlanID") = id

    Dim oLinq As New Linq
    Dim bp As BusinessPlan = oLinq.getBusinessPlanById(id)

    Dim assignedStaff As Staff = oLinq.getStaffById(bp.AssignedStaffID)
    Dim mp As Staff = oLinq.getStaffById(bp.MPStaffID)

    Public Function getBusinessPlanById(ByVal inId As String) As BusinessPlan

        Dim db As New BusinessPlanDataDataContext

        Dim bpItem = (From b In db.BusinessPlans _
                      Select b _
                      Where b.BusinessPlanID = inId).SingleOrDefault

        Return bpItem

    End Function

    'Linq Class --------------------------------------------------------'

    Public Function getStaffById(ByVal inId As String) As Staff

       Dim db As New BusinessPlanDataDataContext

       Dim staffItem = (From s In db.Staffs _
                       Select s _
                       Where s.StaffID = inId).SingleOrDefault

       Return staffItem

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding two references you are saying select all rows where the PK = this and the PK = that. Since the Pk is unique that condition will always be false.

I don't know linq really well but in SQL you would reference the table twice and alias it as in

....
FROM
    tblstaff staff1, tblstaff staff2

Comment: I am using linq to entity framework so visual studio points at the database gets all the relationships and creates objects based on those tables and relationships.